# is there any food for weight loss

Tags: bellyfat

I heard if we drink 4 cups of green tea daily, than we can reduce belly fat

Is green tea will burn the calories ?

if so is there any other solid or liquid foods like this ?

or is all low calories foods will help to reduce belly fat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green tea can help aid in weight loss, but the only way to actually lose weight is to stay in a CALORIC DEFICIT - so your body burns more energy than you give it through food.

Basically as far as I know, green tea has the ability to burn more calories, so it helps you achieve the caloric deficit easily.

As for drinking green tea 4 times a day. I would recommend drinking each cup at the same interval throughout the day for maximum benefits.

Comment: thanks, is there any other solid or liquid food which will help burning calories without any side affects ?

Comment: Green tea is your best bet in terms of no side effects. But caffeine is said to also aid in burning more calories. Although green tea also has caffeine it is not that much as compared to other drinks.

Comment: The best way to lose weight is to count your calories rather than looking for foods to burn fat. Go find out how many calories your body needs (there are multiple online calculators for this) to maintain your current weight and then eat 250-500 less calories than this everyday.

Comment: so if i eat more food with less calories, than it will be no problem right ? `its not about how much we eat, its all about what we eat`, we can eat a lot .... but we should not eat more than the calories needed for our body ? also i mean we can eat lot and lot more proteins but very less carbohydates , right ?

Comment: Yeah you're on the right track. Eating very less carbs is a bad idea, however, as you will feel tired throughout the day. As long as you stay in a caloric deficit and try to balance carbs, protein, fat you should lose weight.  If you want to lose weight eat less than the body burns and vice versa.

Comment: You should add the basis for your weight loss claim since there doesn't seem to be a consensus that green tea will aid in weight loss.

Comment: I said it burns more calories, which is proven.